# How to "newtype" IntSet?

Tags: haskell, types

Thanks to `newtype` and the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension, one can define distinct lightweight types with little effort:

```
newtype PersonId = PersonId Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, NFData, ...)
newtype GroupId  = GroupId Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, NFData, ...)
```

which allows the type-system to make sure a `PersonId` is not used by accident where a `GroupId` was expected, but still inherit selected typeclass instances from `Int`.

Now one could simply define `PersonIdSet` and `GroupIdSet` as

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type PersonIdSet = Set PersonId
type GroupIdSet  = Set GroupId

noGroups :: GroupIdSet
noGroups = Set.empty

-- should not type-check
foo = PersonId 123 `Set.member` noGroups

-- should type-check
bar = GroupId 123 `Set.member` noGroups
```

which is type safe, since map is parametrized by the key-type, and also, the `Set.member` operation is polymorphic so I don't need to define per-id-type variants such as `personIdSetMember` and `groupIdSetMember` (and all other set-operations I might want to use)

...but how can I use the more efficient `IntSet`s instead for `PersonIdSet` and `GroupIdSet` respectively in a similiar way to the example above? Is there a simple way w/o having to wrap/replicate the whole Data.IntSet API as a typeclass?

Comment: IIRC no. But I guess you could use template Haskell.

Comment: You wrote comments saying what should type check and what not. Did you try to compile, where the results different from what you expected?

Comment: @jmg, I just tried to be sure, the results were as expected. The actual error emitted by GHC is `Couldn't match expected type 'PersonId' with actual type 'GroupId'`

Comment: So, the code in your question provides all the properties you are asking, isn't it? Or do you want something else?

Comment: @jmg: yes, but I want those properties with the more efficient `IntSet` instead of the generic `Set`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to wrap `IntSet` as you said.  However, rather than defining each ID type separately, you can introduce a phantom type to create a family of `ID`s and `IDSet`s that are compatible with one another:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet
import Data.IntSet (IntSet)

newtype ID a = ID { unID :: Int }
              deriving ( Eq, Ord, Show, Num )

newtype IDSet a = IDSet { unIDSet :: IntSet }
              deriving ( Eq, Ord, Show )

null :: IDSet a -> Bool
null = IntSet.null . unIDSet

member :: ID a -> IDSet a -> Bool
member i = IntSet.member (unID i) . unIDSet

empty :: IDSet a
empty = IDSet $ IntSet.empty

singleton :: ID a -> IDSet a
singleton = IDSet . IntSet.singleton . unID

insert :: ID a -> IDSet a -> IDSet a
insert i = IDSet . IntSet.insert (unID i) . unIDSet

delete :: ID a -> IDSet a -> IDSet a
delete i = IDSet . IntSet.delete (unID i) . unIDSet
```

So, assuming you have a `Person` type, and a `Group` type, you can do:

```
type PersonID = ID Person
type PersonIDSet = IDSet Person

type GroupID = ID Group
type GroupIDSet = IDSet Group
```

Comment: Looks interesting, I wonder if (and how) this wrapping could be automated with the help of TH, as FUZxxl suggests

Answer (score 4):

The [enummapset](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enummapset) package implements one approach to `newtype`-safe `IntMap`/`IntSet`s.

An example for its usage based on the types from the original question:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import           Data.EnumSet (EnumSet)
import qualified Data.EnumSet as ES

newtype PersonId = PersonId Int deriving Enum
newtype GroupId  = GroupId  Int deriving Enum

type PersonIdSet = EnumSet PersonId
type GroupIdSet  = EnumSet GroupId

noGroups :: GroupIdSet
noGroups = ES.empty

-- fails type-check: Couldn't match expected type `PersonId' with actual type `GroupId'
foo = PersonId 123 `ES.member` noGroups

-- passes type-check
bar = GroupId 123 `ES.member` noGroups
```

The usage of `Data.EnumMap` is similar.

Answer (score -1):

I am under the impression you assume it is less efficient to use a `type` instead of a `newtype`. That is not true, `newtype`s are usually more efficiently implemented than `data`s.

So, your definition of `PersonIdSet` is perfectly safe and as efficient as you might want.

Comment: The inefficiency I was referring to is about `IntSet` vs `Set`