# How to use IntMap with different key types?

Tags: haskell, types

I have a record in a document that use two IntMaps:

```
data Doc = Doc { kernels :: IntMap Kernel, nodes :: IntMap Node }
```

But I found that the keys from both IntMaps have different meaning and I fail to separate in two differents types and don't get errors when mix kernel types and node types. I want to have functions that check the the keys from kernel map and node maps and don't allow mix-up. E.g:

```
someFunction :: Doc -> KernelKey -> NodeKey -> a
someFunction doc k1 k2 = .....
```

Instead of current:

```
someFunction :: Doc -> Int -> Int -> a
someFunction doc k1 k2 = .... -- warning check twice k1 and k2
```

Is it posible? Or I shall change from `IntMap` to `Map`.

Thanks

Comment: What is your reason for using `IntMap` instead of `Map`?  If it's performance then you should consider `unordered-containers` (which might be the best solution for you, but is worth consideration).

Comment: See also the related question about `IntSet` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746590/how-to-newtype-intset ... you might wanna take a look at the [`enummapset` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enummapset), which is what I'm currently using

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `newtype` to make wrappers around `Int` to distinguish their meaning.

```
newtype KernelKey = KernelKey Int
newtype NodeKey = NodeKey Int

someFunction :: Doc -> KernelKey -> NodeKey -> a
someFunction doc (KernelKey k1) (NodeKey k2) = ...
```

That way, you can still use `IntMap` internally, but expose a more type-safe interface, especially if you also control how the `KernelKey` and `NodeKey` values get created, i.e. you don't export their constructors so users only get them as return values from your other functions.

Note that `newtype` wrappers disappear at run time, so this extra wrapping and unwrapping does not affect performance in any way.

Comment: I was confused about the performance. But if the wrapper disappear at run time I'll use your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a unified key type and wrap the IntMap API for your Doc type.  It might look something like this.

```
data DocValue = DocKernel Kernel
              | DocNode Node
data DocKey = KernelKey Int
            | NodeKey Int

docLookup :: DocKey -> Doc -> Maybe DocValue
```

The nice thing about that solution is that you only need one copy of each of the map API functions that you need.  Here's a different solution which is closer to the code you have.

```
newtype NodeKey = NodeKey Int
newtype KernelKey = KernelKey Int
lookupDocNode :: NodeKey -> Doc -> Maybe Node
lookupDocKernel :: KernelKey -> Doc -> Maybe Kernel
```

You could also do this solution without the newtypes.  Both these solutions give you type safety.  In the first one you have to specify what you want with types.  In the second one you specify it by choosing which function to call.

Comment: I don't like the unified key type because always know when I getting one kind of another. I have problems with functions that combine both keys, can be confused: e.g: `lookupNodeHasKernel :: Int -> Int -> Bool`